# Running WAMP on OneDrive

Tags: cloud, wamp, synchronized, onedrive

I have installed WAMP on a sub folder in OneDrive which works perfectly on my local computer. However, I would like to hear about the possibilities of using the same WAMP setup on multiple computers where I've got OneDrive installed.

How can I use WAMP on multiple computers (installed on OneDrive)? Is there a workaround with paths?

Desired result: working on one project on one computer will synchronize on another computer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want MySQL to be updated locally(remotely in one drive) too, or your databases are being updated on server(s)?

Comment: I want all of it to run in the "cloud". Automatically updating on two different computers using same OneDrive @fat_mike

Comment: I don't think its possible to update the local MySQL remotely via OneDrive. Your best bet is to have the database on an online server